# how to get an aws instance given I have the instance's ip

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Given I have an aws instance IP, how can I get the EC2 instance collection object via the ruby aws-sdk's filter option.  For example

```
@ec2.instances.filter(valid_filter_name, ec2_instance_ip)
```

I've tried 'public_ip_address' and 'public_ip' as the filter name but those didn't work.  I'm using this API doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/FilteredCollection.html#filter-instance_method, but it's does not mentioned what the valid parameters are.

Comment: You don't mention the IP address you have.  Every EC2 instance has two IP's, both an internal 10.* address and a publicly addressable IP address.  If you have a 10.* IP then you probably need to filter on a different field name, like 'private_ip' or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the correct parameter to use (by trial & error) is 'ip-address'.  Here's an example:

```
@ec2.instances.filter('ip-address', ec2_instance_ip)
```